# in asp.net WebService, passing a WebControl to a WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webmethod, asp.net-webcontrol

I'm using asp.net 4 ,C# ,VS 2010.
I'm facing a problem by calling a web service method which has a WebControl as a parameter.

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FormsViews
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class FormViews : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void SetCaption(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button bt)
    {
        //Code...
    }
}
```

It compiles with no errors.
On RunTime I get this message:

> The XML element 'EnableTheming' from namespace 'namespace' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

Can you please explain why the webService doesn't accept a WebControl and how to handle this issue?

Comment: Why do you need such a thing? A button belongs to its page and not supposed to be serialized.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this method?  I can see it's called SetCaption() but I dont understand why you're sending a button control?

Comment: the more complete function recieves System.Web.UI.ControlCollection, where I set all captions/texts etc. from my Database to every control.This is passed threw aspx page (this.Page.Controls). I simplified it for the questions. This way I can change language easily. But why is that matter?

Answer (score 0):

The web service does not accept a WebControl because it is not serializable and good web service design does not directly manipulate views or user interfaces. Logic for your views should be left in your views, not in what is typically the business layer. A typical way to handle language support in a view or web page is to make a request to a web service that indicates the language the page should support and it returns a list of labels as key/value pairs.  The key is an ID for the control and the value is what should be displayed in the control.  This is only necessary if your web page uses a lot of Ajax. If you are just rendering the page on the server then you can populate the controls with the correct language when they are rendered on the server. [Here is an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that discusses how to do this.

Comment: I see what you'r saying. If I go with such a method, Can I return a Dictionary with key-value pairs that will represent my ID/Value? SInce this is also seialized so the problem is not solved,...

Comment: @Programmer - You said, "Since this is also serialized so the problems is not solved..."  Why is the problem not solved? The Dictionary is serializeable, while the controls are not. You can return a Dictionary in a web service in many formats. And the other important point I made is that you do not have to even call a web service if you are rendering your pages on the server. Are you rendering the pages on the server?

Comment: It says I cannot return Dictionary since it is IDICTIONARY. I do render them but all the text is from the Database and I want my WebService to support many of my sites. All the DB logic is in the WebService

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: can not be reflected. System.NotSupportedException: The 
type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Comment: Here is a blog that shows one way of serializing a dictionary http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2012/03/06/10060276.aspx. Here is more specific information on localization and globalization of asp.net web apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).aspx.